# Как получить список изображений внутри проекта c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Мне необходимо создать коллекцию емодзи, которые были загружены в проект приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с их использовать? Если я захочу собрать проект и отдать заказчику, то где будут изображения и как их доставать?

Comment: Какой Build Target у картинок? Копируются ли эти файлы в директорию со сборкой? От этого зависит как загрузить.

Comment: А можно по подробнее? Как их указывать? Допустим мне надо чтобы папка Image полностью перенеслась в Debug/Release, что тогда мне нужно сделать?

Comment: В c# есть 2 варианта добавления файлов: 1. Ресурсы (встраивание в .exe/.dll). 2. Директория на диске. Это все настраивается в свойствах файла, где "Действие при сборке" - это внедрить в .exe или нет (если выбрано "Ресурс"), ну а "Копировать в выходной каталог" - это отправлять файлы после сборки в "Debug/Release". Ну и тут сами понимаете, если файлы в ресурсах, то надо работать с ресурсами (что-то наверно типа этого: `Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(...)`, а если файлы на диске, то работа с диском (`Directory.GetFiles(...)`).